# How to associate chrome extension with specific tab?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, robotframework, ui-automation

I am opening chrome extension in a tab instead of pop up with following code:
`chrome-extension://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/popup.html`

But when I do so the extension doesn't get associated with other tab I want to use this extension for. Is there a way I can explicitly tell extension which tab it needs listen to?

Answer (score 2):

From what I researched it's not possible and it is depends on the extension source code. I was able to make adjustments into source code function to create a workaround.
This is how extension selected tab:

```
chrome.tabs.query({
                active: true,
                currentWindow: true
            }, (tabs) => {
                var tab = tabs[0];
```